# Slickgrid inside jquery accordion columns not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

[image]

I am using slickgrid inside a jquery accordion and whenever the page refreshes and the accordion is expanded the columns inside the grid are all out of order and destroyed. I tried using

```
 grid.resizeCanvas();
```

inside my accordion to no avail.

Here is my code.

```
  var grid = (grid1, grid2, grid3);
        $('#accordion').accordion({
            collapsible: true,

            beforeActivate: function (event, ui) {
                grid.resizeCanvas();
                // The accordion believes a panel is being opened
                if (ui.newHeader[0]) {
                    var currHeader = ui.newHeader;
                    var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
                    // The accordion believes a panel is being closed
                } else {
                    var currHeader = ui.oldHeader;
                    var currContent = currHeader.next('.ui-accordion-content');
                }



                // Since we've changed the default behavior, this detects the actual status
                var isPanelSelected = currHeader.attr('aria-selected') == 'true';

                // Toggle the panel's header
                currHeader.toggleClass('ui-corner-all', isPanelSelected).toggleClass('accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top', !isPanelSelected).attr('aria-selected', ((!isPanelSelected).toString()));

                // Toggle the panel's icon
                currHeader.children('.ui-icon').toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-e', isPanelSelected).toggleClass('ui-icon-triangle-1-s', !isPanelSelected);

                // Toggle the panel's content

                currContent.toggleClass('accordion-content-active', !isPanelSelected)
                if (isPanelSelected) { currContent.slideUp(); } else { currContent.slideDown(); }

                return false; // Cancels the default action

            }
        });
```

**Update**
I have tried using

```
 var grid = [grid1, grid2, grid3];
   $("#accordion").accordion({
            afterActivate: function (event, ui) {
                grid[0].resizeCanvas();
            }
        });
```

this has also not worked unfortunately.

Comment: Try making `grid` an array. `var grid = [grid1, grid2, grid3];` then accessing them like `grid[0].resizeCanvas();`

Comment: tried that without any success at the moment. When you close the accordion all of the columns reorganize just prior to the closing animation being completed.

Comment: Is there an `afterActivate` function on the accordion? Typically, the container div needs to be visible and have height for the grid to occupy.

Comment: I dont have an after activate function. If you can show me how that would look and if it works bounty is yours.

Comment: For accordion the function is not `afterActivate()` but [activate()](https://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate). Have you tried that?

Comment: I have also tried that. I am calling accordion again after the first time. The Activate(). function is in the second instance of accordion.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: My ['alternate master' SlickGrid fork](https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid) now contains a fix for the jQuery Accordion issue and a sample page (example-jquery-accordion.html). See https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/1065. I strongly suspect you have additional issues going on here though.

Comment: also see: https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/pull/4#issuecomment-100419965

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `window.location.reload()` and when the page is reloaded the grid columns are aligned as expected. I have tried doing this inside a recursive method call instead of reloading the page and experienced the issue you describe.

If you can refresh the page instead of doing a recursive call then that would solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the "resizeCanvas()" method is not affecting the columns.
I hate to do this but try to loop through the columns again and resize them and let me know if that works for you:
Example

```
    var grid = [grid1, grid2, grid3];
   $("#accordion").accordion({
            afterActivate: function (event, ui) {
                var cols = grid[0].getColumns();
                cols[0].width = 120; 
                grid[0].setColumns(cols);`
            }
        });
```

You don't have to loop through the columns like I did. You know the columns name and sizes so you can do this

```
cols["Policy Type"].width = 120;
```

and so forth.. Let me know if that helped

Comment: Excellent Idea but did not yield results.